# Jython listed by `getEngineFactories`, but `getEngineByName("jython")` is `null`

Tags: java, python, jython, jsr223

I created a default Maven Java project and added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.python</groupId>
  <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I created a package `src/main/java/mypkg` and added this class:

```
package mypkg;

import javax.script.*;

class JythonMinimalTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String engineName = "python";
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName(engineName);
        if (engine == null) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: `" + engineName + "` not available.");
            System.err.println("Available engines: ");
            for (ScriptEngineFactory factory: manager.getEngineFactories()) {
                System.err.println(factory);
                System.err.println("names:");
                for (String name: factory.getNames()) {
                    System.err.println("  " + name);
                }
            }
            System.exit(999);
        }
        engine.eval("print('hello, world')");
    }
}
```

When I run it using `exec:java`,

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=mypkg.JythonMinimalTest
```

I get the following mysterious output:

```
ERROR: `python` not available.
Available engines: 
org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngineFactory@2b0e6c89
names:
  python
  jython
jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory@46618cb8
names:
  nashorn
  Nashorn
  js
  JS
  JavaScript
  javascript
  ECMAScript
  ecmascript
```

The manager returns `null`, but then in the next line lists `python`/`jython` among the available script engines.

Nashorn worked just fine in exactly the same way. What am I doing wrong with Jython?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025866/2834978

Comment: @ElliottFrisch maven uses both 1.8: `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>`, the java itself is also `1.8.0`.

Comment: What happens if you use `jython-standalone` as artifactId instead of `jython` (see comment by Luis Muñoz)?

Comment: @mzjn Indeed, with jython-standalone 2.7.1, I don't need any `Option.loadSite=false` hacks, it works as expected right away. Note that `jython-standalone.jar` takes 40MB instead of 30MB. This solution is mentioned in {the question linked by Andrew in {the question linked by Luis Muñoz}}: [whats-the-difference-between-jython-standalone-2-7-0-jar-and-jython-2-7-0-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061490/whats-the-difference-between-jython-standalone-2-7-0-jar-and-jython-2-7-0-jar), but it has no accepted answers...

Comment: There are other similar questions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/17749799/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14641917/407651. The `Lib` subdirectory with standard Python modules (including site.py) is included in jython-standalone.jar but not in jython.jar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one workaround:

Add this at the top:

```
import org.python.core.Options;
```

Before invoking `getEngineByName`, set

```
   Options.importSite = false;
```

Then the engine is created without problems.

Got the solution from [this conversation](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/2-7b3-JSR-223-ScriptEngine-null-b2-works-td5074755.html).

---

Another solution that works well (proposed by mzjn in the comments) is to replace the `jython` artifact by `jython-standalone`.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to disable `importSite` with python Options, as you already discovered. Or, set the `python.home` to where you have extracted `jython`. I have it extracted in my home folder under `jython2.7.0`; adding this,

```
System.setProperty("python.home", new File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), "jython2.7.0").getPath()
);
```

allows python to discover the correct `PYPATH` so it can build the python environment.

Comment: Forgive me this possibly dumb question, but what do you mean by "extract"? I didn't extract anything anywhere, I just added five lines to the POM and hoped that I can use the engine just like any other dependency. I'm afraid that I still don't understand what the `importSite` option does, and what `site.py` is good for. Will I get into trouble as soon as I try to go beyond `print('hello')` if `site.py` isn't imported? What difference does it make?

Comment: Install jython using the [installer file](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-installer/2.7.0/jython-installer-2.7.0.jar) from their website, it contains a `Lib` folder. That contains a bunch of `python` modules that it uses to form the base python system. So you can `import io` or `import pickle` etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to set the env var `jythonpath` to include the specific `Lib` directory you need for your instance (and include the `Lib\site-packages` as well to avoid further issues with specific packages)