# Can't create Netbeans JAR files

Tags: java, python-3.x, netbeans-8

I’m a novice programmer and I bit off more than I could chew. I’m using Netbeans 8.2 for the first time and I managed to hobble it together and install the Python 3.0 plugin followed by the Jython 2.7 plugin (never used either of these before.) I’m a model railroader and use a program call JMRI (but not its JAR file in my code) which is written in Java and my code is for trains so I chose Jython so I could share it with others.
I have a good working program! Now I want to create JAR files so I can share it. Clean & build does nothing, I click it and the output window remains blank. I right click the project and see Clean and make egg. Researching the internet I find that I’m not the only one that has struggled with making Jython JAR files. But the Q& A are dated (2011-2014) and refer to programs JUMP and JthonC which appear to be unavailable now.
I’m looking for tutorials and examples and of course experienced users to guide me. What program (or plugin) do I need to make the JAR file?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825576/2970947

Comment: Okay guys a moment of panic for me ...... Looking at my project properties it shows I have a Python project with Python Platform Jython2.7.0 and my path points to <snip>Python.exe and <snip>Jython.exe.
Did I create my code under the wrong platform? Should this have been a Java platform?

Comment: DON'T PANIC. I'm not a netbeans expert. I have used it. But not for quite a while. Focus on the desired outcome. I **highly** recommend using standard tooling like `maven` and most IDEs can use that. And everything should be [okay](https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html). I think you want a "Java Project" if you ultimately intend to build a Java Fat-JAR executable.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, I've just discovered Maven and am now trying to figure out how to migrate an existing Python/Jython project into it. Since the terms are all new the reading with comprehension is slow and painful especially at age 72.

Comment: This link might be helpful: [Adding external JAR to Maven project in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17693040/2985643).